# Verify JWT using google auth library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, cryptography, jwt

I am trying to validate a JWT generated by Google IAP based on this [example](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto). I am using App Engine and Python 3.7 and that means I can't use the same library  as the example since it won't [work](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/iap#using-validate_jwt) with App Engine.

Looking for alternatives I tried using [google.auth](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/tree/master/google/auth) but it is not working with any JTW. I created this token as an example using the tool in https://jwt.io::

```py
from google.auth import jwt
token = 'eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IkxZeVAyZyJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.OjJokSnHIdMxqTlpT055GJDe72-zoTZBE5NISmrDPx0dletHBTnlbl1wwr0EhWaxgKIesZ7N7eLd4XW-TgX-vA'
cert = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEEVs/o5+uQbTjL3chynL4wXgUg2R9\nq9UU8I5mEovUf86QZ7kOBIjJwqnzD1omageEHWwHdBO6B+dFabmdT9POxg==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n'
jwt.decode(token, certs=cert)
```

But got the following error:

```
/tests/jwt/google_auth/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rsa/pem.py", line 92, in load_pem
    raise ValueError('No PEM start marker "%s" found' % pem_start)
ValueError: No PEM start marker "b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----'" found
```

which makes me wonder why the jwt module can't decode a token created with the EC256 algorithm since is the algorithm used by Google IAP.

So anyone have an idea of why this is happening?
Can you recommend an alternative?

*Note*: Looking for other alternatives I also found the [ecdsa](https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa) python implementation but I'm not allowed to use this one (securyty team won't allow this one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently it is not possible to validate a JWT using ES256 with google auth: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/issues/336#issuecomment-486748042

So if someone out there is trying to do this using app engine your only alternative is this:
https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete this sections `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` from key before

Comment: I don't think is a good idea to mess up with the public key and either way the marker is needed to determine what type of key is used

Comment: You don't need to change the key itself. You just can remove this sections from key copy